# What is the maximum width of a widget that's allowed to be created in Windows CE

Tags: c++, windows, windows-ce

We are trying to create a widget of width larger than 2^15 pixels and the widget gets only black (no content shown) when we pass the 2^15 pixel barrier. Is there any documented maximum size limits imposed on widgets?

Any help is appreciated. Not only CE but I am interested in desktop Windows as well.

P.S: Using C++

Comment: Wha? What do you mean by "widgets" exactly, and what language is this? Java, .Net?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could find on [MSDN Control.Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.size.aspx) was this:

> On Windows Server 2003 systems, the
>   size of a Form is restricted by the
>   maximum pixel width and height of the
>   monitor.

I imagine the same would be true on a handheld running Windows CE.

Comment: That would restrict us by 800x480 which is not the case here.